# How hard to solve the given mod problem

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let c = a.b mod p

where p is n bit prime number (e.g. 128 or 160 bit prime number);
a - random number between 1 and (p-1);
b - random number between 1 and (p-1);

Given c, a and p, how hard to compute b?

Comment: See [Modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) on wikipedia.

Answer (score 8):

Very easy, you just use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to compute $a^{-1} \pmod p$. Then you have $b \equiv ca^{-1} \pmod p$.

Note that, because the EEA has polynomial complexity, this remains easy even if $p$ is *very* large (*e.g.*, tens of thousands of bits).

Answer (score 1):

Easy, regardless of the bit length of $p$. You can calculate $b = c \cdot a^{-1} \mod p$ directly. $a^{-1}$ exists and can be calculated directly from $a$.